# Why is product not being deleted instead it is redirected to another page?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, crud, laravel-8

My delete function is not working. Instead it is redirecting to singleProduct page. What might be the error? Is there any mistake in delete form?
I have one product listing page and that consists of edit button. When edit button is clicked it redirects to a form which contains update and delete button. When delete button is clicked it should be redirected to deleteProduct page but it is redirected to singleProduct page and product is not deleted.

These are all my routes:

```
Route::get('/products',[ProductController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/products',[ProductController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/products/create',[ProductController::class, 'create']);
Route::get('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class, 'show'])->name('singleProduct');
Route::get('/products/{id}/edit',[ProductController::class, 'edit'])->name('editProduct');
Route::put('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class, 'update'])->name('updateProduct');

Route::delete('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class, 'delete'])->name('deleteProduct');
```

This is my editProduct.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts/masterlayout')
@section('title', 'All Products')
@section('mainbody')
<div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
<form method = "POST" action="../../products/{{$product->id}}">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input type = "text" class="form-control input @error('title') is-danger @enderror" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
        @error('title')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('title')}}</p>
        @enderror
    <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Type</label>
        <input type = "text" class="form-control  input @error('type') is-danger @enderror" name="type" value="{{$product->type}}">
        @error('type')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('type')}}</p>
        @enderror

    <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type ="number" class="form-control input @error('price') is-danger @enderror" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
        @error('price')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('price')}}</p>
        @enderror
    <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type ="text" class="form-control input @error('firstname') is-danger @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{$product->firstname}}">
        @error('firstname')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('firstname')}}</p>
        @enderror
    <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input type ="text" class="form-control input @error('price') is-danger @enderror" name="surname" value="{{$product->surname}}">
        @error('surname')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('surname')}}</p>
        @enderror
    <div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Playlength/ PageNumber</label>
        <input type ="number" class="form-control  input @error('papl') is-danger @enderror" name="papl" value="{{$product->papl}}">
        @error('papl')
            <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('papl')}}</p>
        @enderror
    <div>
    <br/>
    <button type = "submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
<a href="{{ route('deleteProduct',$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is my deleteProduct.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts/masterlayout')
@section('title', 'All Products')
@section('mainbody')
<form method = "POST" action="../../products/{{$product->id}}">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <input type = "text" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
    <label>Product Type</label>
    <input type = "text" name="type" value="{{$product->type}}">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type ="number" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input type ="text" name="firstname" value="{{$product->firstname}}">
    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type ="text" name="surname" value="{{$product->surname}}">
    <label>Playlength/ PageNumber</label>
    <input type ="number" name="papl" value="{{$product->papl}}">
</form>
@endsection
```

This is my delete function  of ProductController.php

```
public function destroy(Product $id)
    {
         $id->delete();     
         return redirect('/products'); 

    }
```

Comment: Do a `dd()` in the destroy function and see if it's reaching this function. Also are you using `soft delete`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the action destroy not delete in your Web.php file

```
Route::delete('/products/{id}',[ProductController::class, 'destroy'])->name('deleteProduct');
```

Comment: I changed it but it's not working, it's redirected to singleProduct page

Comment: There was mistake in form and it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

for work model route binding you need to use
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding

```php
Route::delete('/products/{product}',[ProductController::class, 'destroy'])->name('deleteProduct');
```

then

```php
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
     $product->delete();     
     return redirect('/products'); 

}
```

> **here function parameter name must match with route segment name**

---

#### Else in another way

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
     $product = Product::findOrFail($id);  
     $product->delete();   
     return redirect('/products'); 

}
```